# How to write $\aleph$ by hand

Tags: soft-question, notation

So far, I've only seen the symbol $\aleph$ in its printed form and am wondering how this symbol could be written **by hand** on paper or on a board (in mathematical contexts, of course). Whenever I try to write it, I seem to have two options:

- *Paper:* Unwrap my nib and attempt a nice piece of calligraphy. (However, this is a bit too time-consuming.)
  *Board:* Rotate the chalk to produce a broader line. (However, this only works with chalk of appropriate length.)
- Approximate the printed form $\aleph$ as good as I can holding the pen/chalk ordinarily. (However, this leads to a letter that can hardly be distinguished from an $N$ or $\chi$ or $X$.)

So, how can I produce a neat, distinguishable $\aleph$ by hand (in a reasonable amount of time)? And in what order should the strokes and wiggles be written?

Comment: This link might help: http://www.quora.com/Should-I-learn-the-Hebrew-cursive-or-printed-alphabet-first.  Note that the context of that post is not mathematics, but there are some nice images of what a hand-printed aleph should look like.

Comment: @mweiss The link is broken.

Comment: Odd, it works for me.

Comment: Three strokes, all downwards: diagonal first, then upper right then lower left. http://www.hebrew4christians.com/Grammar/Unit_One/Aleph-Bet/Aleph/aleph.html gives some advice, through mathematicians should avoid the cursive form.

Comment: Another source is at http://www.behrmanhouse.com/resource_room/hebrew-handwriting-chart.  However, you are right that it is likely to end up looking like an $X$ if you are not careful.  To avoid that, make the two shorter diagonal strokes offset slightly (so that they do not go directly through the center of the main diagonal) and slightly non-parallel.

Comment: It's usually written like like the typewritten version: a diagonal stroke, then two separate strokes in the bottom-left and upper-right (though I write the former first). To avoid making it look just like an $X$, I avoid joining up the two separate strokes to the diagonal, and make the latter slightly wiggly rather than a straight line. In particular, the handwritten math aleph looks absolutely nothing like the aleph in modern cursive Hebrew.

Comment: @mweiss Actually the link works for the signed-in users of the site.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

This is the letter א as commonly taught to schoolchildren in Israel:

[image]

If I remember correctly, we used to draw the main diagonal first, starting at the top left, then the upper arm starting from the top and angling towards the main line, then the lower leg starting from the main diagonal and curving downwards.

There's no need to use a particularly thick stroke; the letters are written with the same stroke style as letters in Latin and other alphabets.

Comment: Hallellu-Yah!  Someone who knows gave a ***useful*** answer!  ***Endorsed!!!***

Comment: Why would Israeli students be taught how to draw the block form rather than the written form (which looks like "IC")?

Comment: They get taught both. At least they were when I was a kid, back in the mists of time.

Answer (score 5):

I have always written it as three disconnected strokes:

[image]

and as far as I know, nobody has ever had trouble recognizing it.

Answer (score 3):

I usually don't try any bolding or curling - I just draw a diagonal line for the "main" line, and two vertical "legs" jutting out of it. To keep $\aleph$ distinct from $X$ or $\chi$, I make sure to space the "legs" out away from the middle and not too close to the endpoints (to keep it distinct from $N$), at about the one-third and two-third points laterally. I also write $\aleph$ slightly larger than the other symbols. This seems to work well.

Also, I often leave a slight gap between the left leg and the main line. You can also slope the legs a bit to the right so they aren't vertical (if you do this you need to be extra careful to keep the legs away from the center).

I stay away from bolding, curling, etc. just because I've not found it helps much, and it slows me down.

Comment: I don't think that I saw boldface script Hebrew letters written by hand in recent memory.

Comment: I've seen blackboard bold (the double-lining), or the side of the chalk, used for the main line of the $\aleph$; I didn't like it very much.

Comment: Sounds quite bad. But I'll be willing to accept all the bad $\aleph$ typography in the world, if people will start pronouncing "Neeman", "Magidor" and more importantly "Shelah" properly! :-)

Answer (score 0):

https://youtu.be/9SobGFa0Jac?t=63

Minute 1:05, I think you need a special pen for writing in paper, but I think you will be able to do it with a chalk.

Answer (score -1):

My answer to this old question might still be useful for those who, like me, come here from a search. I was looking for a better method than mine, but still prefer what I did.

The answers given are all correct for language writing. I also needed to do alefs in a mathematical context (transfinite numbers) and had no idea how, just the printed form. For my purposes I found a loop on the end of the short arms made a character that I could recognize in my notes.

**A diagonal like a backslash, 1/3 from the bottom an up-right diagonal with a loop on the end, 2/3 from the bottom a down-left diagonal with a loop.**

Recognizably like the printed version, and easy to pick out.

I haven't done this for years, and am totally useful at mouse graphics, but something like this:

[image: A diagonal like a backslash, 1/3 from the bottom an up-right diagonal with a loop on the end, 2/3 from the bottom a down-left diagonal with a loop.]